# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I got "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'name' doesn't have a default value" when i save.

my save method

```
 gender = genderServices.getById(Integer.parseInt(carMap.get("gender").toString()));
        category.setGender(gender);
        category.setCategoryName(carMap.get("categoryName").toString());
        this.categoryServices.save(category);
```

Gender.class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;
```

Category class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="genderID")
private Gender gender;
```

How to i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explainable, it does mean their is "not null constraint" for "name" in db and you are not setting any value against the column.

Comment: Usually real SQL structure is not coherent with JPA (for example JPA definiotions goes to never versions, db not)

Comment: No i set a value of name with category.setGender(gender).So gender name is not null when save